# How to implement a for loop in Jsonata

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xquery, jsonata

I am looking to convert xquery to jsonata ,

```
let $h := $at//datahistory
for $x in 0 to (count($h))
let p:= (if (not($h[$x]/daytoday =(‘one’, ‘two’) )) then ‘ZERO’ else $h[$x+1]/Status 
return if(index-of($p) > 0 then 0 else 1)
```

Any kind of assistance and help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your input data and desired result

Comment: You have tagged this [tag:c#] but [tag:jsonata] is an npm package for use in javascript apps.  How are you using this in c#?  Or should this actually be tagged [tag:javascript]?

Comment: Sorry it is not with C#

Answer (score 1):

Your XQuery is a `for` expression that can be easily rewritten as a simple XPath path expression `/bookstore/book[price > 30]/title` which would translate to a JSONata path `bookstore.book[price > 30].title`. On the other hand it is unlikely that the JSON data has such a structure with `bookstore` and `book`, I guess an object with an array property like

```
{
  "bookstore" : [
    {
      "title" : "title 1",
      "price" : 20
    },
    {
      "title" : "title 2",
      "price" : 35
    },
    {
      "title" : "title 3",
      "price" : 99
    }
  ]
}
```

which leads to `bookstore[price > 30].title` (https://try.jsonata.org/0vfDXqv4m) or a simple array with the book objects

```
 [
    {
      "price": 20,
      "title": "title 1"
    },
    {
      "price": 35,
      "title": "title 2"
    },
    {
      "price": 99,
      "title": "title 3"
    }
]
```

which leads to `$[price > 30].title` (https://try.jsonata.org/fryxG-QLj) is more likely.

Comment: Hi Martin , I want to parse the array .Example below : for $i 1 to 100 $h := if(not($i > 10)  then 0 else ‘0’

Comment: @ABobba, consider to edit your question and to show a sample of the JSON you have.

Comment: Hello @martin ,I have updated my query ... I wanted to convert that xquery to jsonata

Comment: @ABobba, at least show the JSON you want to query with JSONata, simply saying I want to convert XQuery to JSONata doesn't seem to make sense. And editing the code in a question to something completely different once you got an answer on the first code sample doesn't make much sense either.